# How to display currency code in invoice template?

Tags: template, payment, currency

I want to display currency code which was used for payment in invoice template. Currency code like CAD, USD . I have not found any directive for this. Please help me.

Comment: In invoice pdf or emai template. It's better to attach screenshot

Comment: In invoice email template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the code to local folder from `Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php` and after that add the given function...

```
public function getOrderCurrency()
{
    $currency = $this->getOrder()->getOrderCurrencyCode();
    $text = Mage::helper('core')->__('Order was placed using %s',$currency);
    return $text;
}
```

In the invoice email template,
For Currency Code use

```
{{var invoice.getOrderCurrency()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite or copy the code from Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php to local folder and add the below function

```
public function getOrderCurrency()
    {
        $currency = $this->getOrder()->getOrderCurrencyCode();
        $text = Mage::helper('core')->__('Order was placed using %s',$currency);
        return $text;
    }
```

In invoice email template,after `{{var payment_html}}` get the order currency as `{{var invoice.getOrderCurrency()}}`. Like this you can add any number of functions and access in email templates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:-

```
 $storeid = 1; /* change store id according to yours*/
 $currencyCode =  Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); 

$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($currencyCode)->getSymbol();
```

For Editing in invoice you have to modify these file and obviously overwirte them in local pool not in core file

> /app/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
>
> /app/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php